# How to force element to fit inside 100vh

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create two side by side panes in bootstrap. The entire page should have a height of 100vh with no scroll bar for the page.

However there should be a scroll bar in the left content tab. Instead with the code I have it is not accounting for the height of my h1 element and there is a scrollbar for left content and the entire page. How can I make it so the only scrollbar is in the box for left content. Sorry for my bad job explaining, but if you visit the fiddle it will be really obvious.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7uauho0d/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="pg-container">


  <h1>
  TITLE AT TOP
  </h1>

  <div class="col-xs-8" id="left">
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
      <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
    <h1>LEFT CONTENT</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4" id="right">

    <h1>
RIGHT CONTENT
RIGHT CONTENT
   </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pg-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

#left {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  /* When I specify 100% here, I expect it to take into account the <h1> at the top
  so that this element is the height of the viewport minus the height of the title at
  the top. I expect only 1 scrollbar, the one inside left content, there should be no
  scrollbar for the page*/

  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent container that has `height: 100vh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with the utilization of [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), setting `overflow: hidden` on the parent container that has `height: 100vh` should work.

check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7uauho0d/7/

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but my question is more complicated than that. The title should always be visible. It's about getting the proper height for the left content box

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-y: hidden` to the outer div:

```
#pg-container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden
}
```

If you want to disable horizontal scrolling as well, you can just use `overflow: hidden` instead.

The title bar at the top should always be visible. Although you can always enforce that with `position: absolute` and `top: 0`.

Comment: Not what I'm trying to do, please visit the fiddle i posted.

Comment: Your question was not very clear. For example, you mention that in your fiddle that the sizing wasn't accounting for the height of your h1 element. I did reference your fiddle, and just about every child element is an h1 element. I cant assume that you downvoted my answer, but if you did, it is not entirely my fault that the answer does not answer your question. You should accept some responsibility for posting an ambiguous question.